# How can I get a value from a memory address that changes almost every millisecond?

Tags: memory, game-hacking, cheat-engine

After a lot of time, I found an address in the memory that has the target value but there is something unusual in that address! that address changes every millisecond.

ScreenShot:
[image]

I did a hardware breakpoint on that line `MOV ecx, [DOSBox.exe+210BF4]`.
When the turn comes to that line, this memory address `DOSBox.exe+210BF4` becomes holder to the target value and then the `ECX` register takes that value from it.

I am sure that the target value comes from this address but I don't know how can I get the value from that strange address. Is there a solution?

Comment: How about a hardware breakpoint on the memory location? That will stop the program and enter the debugger whenever the location is changed.

Comment: If the value is really changing so often then (without a proper synchronization) the code also doesn't know what value it will get. Assuming the values follow a pattern it might be an anti-debugging measure. By reading it's value multiple times one could try to assume the execution time and thus detect a debugger.

Comment: @BrendanDolan-Gavitt: I have updated my question, and I have answered your words.

Comment: @Robert: Unfortunately, this matter is not easy to predict, and one must know the mechanism to that pattern, although that game is very old from the dos era.

Comment: no hwbp on mov ecx , line set hwbp on like (windbg syntax)  ba w1 DOSBox.exe+210BF4  it should stop when someone writes to that location  then look at the call stack kb in windbg

Comment: I'm not understanding why you don't just fetch the value out of memory yourself? That instruction is just a load from memory at a particular address within `DOSBox.exe`. You can compute that address yourself and read the value from it.

Comment: @RolfRolles: I have already fetched the value but it's a dynamic address, and I couldn't get the static address of that value.

Comment: What do you mean? The instruction that you highlighted, `MOV ecx, [DOSBox.exe+210BF4]`, is always accessing the same address. From the image you showed, the *value* is changing each time the breakpoint hit, but the *address* is not.

Comment: @RolfRolles: Regarding your previous comment, what did you mean by "You can compute that address yourself and read the value from it." and how can I get the value from its source place?

Comment: mr lion the address dosbox+xxxx is a static address except for aslr the miv ecx is a dereference  your address is not changing as rolf has pointed out right from the outset

Comment: Yes, it's as @blabb just said: take the address of DOSBox.exe in memory and add 0x210BF4 to it. Something like: 

```
HMODULE db = GetModuleHandle("DOSBox.exe");
char *pDb = (char *)db;
int *pMyVar = (int *)&pDb[0x210BF4];
printf("My variable is %d\n", *pMyVar);
```

Comment: @blabb: I thought like you that this address `DOSBox.exe+210BF4` the static address that always contains the target value (max fuel value), but when using its value to the current fuel value I found the fuel became 0, and that means the address doesn't always contain "max fuel value".  Also, I noticed another thing that static address takes the target value from another dynamic variable.

Comment: Well, it sounds like your initial assumption that you had found the proper location in memory was wrong. You can even see it flash to 0 in the animated image in your post. You should go back to the drawing board and find a better location. Alternatively, perhaps it is the correct location, but the value is being set to 0 for a "good" reason (i.e., the programmers did that deliberately) -- in that case, figure out why.

Comment: @RolfRolles I dont think the 0 value is necessarily an issue, it's not a pointer (assumedly?) he just needs to read from DOSBox.exe+210BF4.  Remind me, I'm about to write a C++ function to parse `[[[address + x] + y] + z] + w` style addresses, and i'm disinclined to read delphi source (cheatengine) to steal theirs :)